# What is the equivalent of PL/SQL %NOTFOUND in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, plsql, cursor, plpgsql

Everything's in the title.

I am Looping on a cursor and would like to have the

```
EXIT WHEN curs%NOTFOUND
```

when there is no more row, what is the equivalent of %NOTFOUND under PostgreSQL ?

**Edit**

Or the other cursors attributes %ISOPEN, %EMPTY, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Can't test this right now but what if you try this?
Check out section title 37.7.3.2. EXIT at this link
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

```
IF NOT FOUND THEN
    EXIT;
END IF;
```

OR

```
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
```

Comment: its giving error ERROR:  column "found" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT NOT FOUND     
code{BEGIN
OPEN pan_tan;
LOOP
FETCH pan_tan INTO rcrd;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;}

Answer (score 1):

The [FOUND](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) variable

Implicit cursor

```
SELECT * INTO myrec FROM emp WHERE empname = myname;
IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'employee % not found', myname;
END IF;
```

With an explicit cursor

```
...   
    LOOP
        FETCH cursor INTO whatever;
        EXIT IF NOT FOUND;
           do something with whatever
    end LOOP;
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I am looking for. I am aware of this function, but here you are not using any cursor but a SELECT query. Did you get my point ?

Comment: Did you try this ? I had try and got an error because of the IF NOT FOUND.

Comment: What version of the database are you on and what was the error you get?  Can you post your code?